# How to manipulate headsep only on text pages

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

The space between headings and chapter or section titles is a frequently answered issue. But what if I want to keep that distance but reduce the space between heading and text on pages without a title?

I write my thesis using `scrreprt` and I am currently forced to squeeze two huge photographs and some text on one page. So I need to reduce the space between heading and text without changing the layout of pages that start with a chapter or section.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm, top=35mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[headsepline, plainheadsepline, automark]{scrpage2} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\chead[]{\headmark} 
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark} 
\cfoot[]{}
\automark{chapter}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize} 

\setlength{\headsep}{0.5cm} 
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{0cm}} 
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrplain}
\chapter{A chapter}
some text

The distance to the heading is okay.
\newpage
\section{Another line}
here goes some text too.

The distance here is too small.
\newpage
This is the part I aimed for. It should be that close. 
\end{document}
```

As you can see changing headsep moves the section as far up as the normal text. I have tried the `titlesec`-package and some redefinitions like this ([german golatex thread](http://www.golatex.de/abstand-vor-bzw-nach-subsection-zum-fliesstext-t6042.html)) without getting it back in its normal position but it seems impossible without changing back 'headsep'. But there must be a way to disconnect these two spaces, right? I would really appreciate some help and shared knowledge since I am fairly new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

In your case a better approach would be not to redefine `\headsep`, but to add a manual `\vspace*`. The star is important here, otherwise a `\vspace` in the beginning (and also in the end) of a page would be without effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm, top=35mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[headsepline, plainheadsepline, automark]{scrpage2} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\chead[]{\headmark} 
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark} 
\cfoot[]{}
\automark{chapter}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize} 

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{0cm}} 
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrplain}
\chapter{A chapter}
some text

The distance to the heading is okay.
\newpage
\section{Another line}
here goes some text too.

The distance here was too small, but is now according to the standard.
\newpage
\vspace*{-0.75cm}

This is the part I aimed for. It should be that close. 
\end{document}
```

After `\vspace*` the empty line could be left out, but for consistency I left it in, because after `\vspace` it would otherwise have an undesired effect.

---

Note, that meanwhile a successor for `scrpage2` was published with version 3.12 of KOMA-Script: Its name is `scrlayer-scrpage`. It is downwards compatible to `scrpage2`, but fixes some pecularities and offers more opportunities.

Comment: I revisited the question today because it was not marked as answered. Your answer fixed the problem I described - thanks for that! I guess I waited for another solution, that changed the issue for all pages at once since I had to fix about 200 pages like that...